# Why is this code not working to modify HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have implemented this code on my site:

```
$('.feed-item').append('<p> This is paragraph element. </p>');
```

on this page here: [Test](http://yourdailyarsenal.com/yda-blogs/)

however the code isn't working, it is definitely there as I can see it in the page source however nothing is happening. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You have an invalid script `<script></p>
<p>$('.feed-item').append('
<p> This is paragraph element. </p>
<p>');</p>
<p></script>`

Comment: Your console has an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: @ArunPJohny That hasn't worked either

Comment: look at your browser console, you still have errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` - it is because you have new line characters in between the string literal

Comment: @Mike: Can i know what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @Mike http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/reLLnowh/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it works on Js Fiddle but when i add it to the page it doesn't work

Comment: @Mike If you go to view source of your page, you could see that the string  is broken into multiple line causing an error - `$('.feed-item').append('<p> This is paragraph element. </p>');` should be in one line - in your page the script is like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/reLLnowh/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's all correct now, but still not working

Comment: @Mike read my answer.

Comment: now that script itself is not visible in the page... did you move it to a script file

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I just noticed in your page jQuery is defined as jQuery and not as $.**

In your page you have new lines in your string which causes the error. This:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.feed-item').append('
<p> This is paragraph element. </p>
<p>');
});
```

should be:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.feed-item').append('<p> This is paragraph element. </p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse the DOM is not loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.feed-item').append('<p> This is paragraph element. </p>');
});
```

or put it at the bottom on the page after the HTML.

`<p>` is also not valid in script.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
 $('.feed-item').append('</p><p> This is paragraph element. </p><p>');
```

Answer (score -2):

please add this code snippet to footer.php before`</html>` tag and remove from your previous location

```
<script>
$('.feed-item').append('<p> This is paragraph element. </p>');
</script>
```

Comment: Scripts should stay just before the closing of <body> tag, not after </html>.

Comment: @madagalbiati ,if i put it after </html> tag it will not work?

Comment: @madagalbiati  some time we need to place script at the end.. it's not hard and fast rule to write a script before body

Comment: Not everything that works should be done. If that is the rule you use for development, chances are your code will get very messy.

Comment: @AmitSoni There is a deeper discussion about this in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup if you guys are interested.